# Pubcenter Alternatives

Tags: windows-8

I have an app published in the Windows store with pubcenter ads but after the recent drop in fill rates ([see here](http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2013/05/03/microsoft-quiet-as-windows-8-developers-decry-low-ad-fill-rates-in-apps-distributed-through-the-nascent-windows-store/)) these adverts a providing effectively no revenue (maybe £0.01 in a day occasionally). I wonder if any one knows of any alternatives for advertising.

I have looked at inmobi but their sdk seems to only have out of date documentation that does not work. AdDuplex is also not an option as it is not available for HTML/JS apps.

Comment: Pubcenter is a trash...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit your app into differents advertising such as [Smatoo](https://my.smaato.com/selfservice/showlogin.do) or ad Exchanges like [adDuplex](https://www.adduplex.com/).

An ad exchange is a marketplace which allows buying and selling advertisements online in real time. The ad exchanges allow applicants spaces (eg advertisers or agencies) and suppliers, comparing real-time supply and demand advertising and automate the buying and selling spaces publicitaires.Ils also allow, once the defined criteria, almost completely automate the implementation of campaigns.

You can also use [Adrotator](http://wp7adrotator.codeplex.com/) which allows you to change advertising rule if it does not send you any advertisements. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different PubCenter Alternatives like:

```
AdDuplex (included with the release as a NuGet package)
Inmobi
Smaato
Google AdMob
MobFox
Inneractive
```

After you can use an AdRotatorV2 for Windows Phone (https://github.com/Adrotator/AdrotatorV2)  which allows you so show different ads and also home made ads.

Personally I use PubCenter and AdDuplex.

Answer (score 0):

I think other ad providers will make sdk for Windows 8 apps once the platform gets more succes. Pubcenter will have to fix things or developers will flock away. Microsoft knows this I suppose...

Answer (score 0):

There is an promotion platform http://adshufflr.com. It shows advertisement, when Pubcenter fails to provide ad.

The best part: only 2 line changes are required to add this network as fallback.
For every 10 ads displayed in your app, you get credit for 9 ads. Which is used in promoting your app.

This all i can say as i am using AdShufflr. Started seeing increase in app downloads